# Not getting ip when running dhcpcd wlan0 inside startup script

Tags: networking, systemd

Rasbian on a Rasberry PI zero.

I have disabled the networking and dhcpcd services from startup and want to start networking and get an IP from within my own script, which is initiated from a custom systemd service.

This is the part of the script that is puzzling me:

```
wpa_passphrase ssid password > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
systemctl start networking.service
dhcpcd wlan0
```

Running dhcpcd wlan0 from within the script will not assign an IP (ifconfig after login), but running sudo dhcpcd wlan0 will get me an IP if I run it after startup and login. Anyone know if this is a timing issue (wait for networking.service) or if I need to do something differently to get an IP via dhcpcd within the script.

I have also tried adding some delay (sleep 100) and running systemctl start dhcpcd (instead of dhcpcd wlan0).

I know this is not the standard way of doing this, but disabling networking and dhcpcd and start it from within my script will make startup more efficient (less up/down and waiting for network before doing more initiation etc.). I do a lot of custom configuration and instantiation from within my script.

Henrik

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself:

I had to change the /etc/network/interfaces configuration file. I changed:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

To:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

This also means that I can remove the dhcpcd wlan0 line in the script. Now I get an IP at startup, even when initiating the networking service from within the script.